# Share volumes between docker stacks?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have two different docker stacks, one for HBase and one for Spark.  I need to get the HBase jars into the spark path.  One way that I can do this, without having to modify the spark containers is to use a volume. In my docker-compose.yml for HBase, I have defined a volume that points to the HBase home (it happens to be /opt/hbase-1.2.6).  Is it possible to share that volume with the spark stack?

Right now, since the service names are different (2 different docker-compose files) the volumes are being prepended (hbase_hbasehome and spark_hbasehome) causing the share to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an `external` volume. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) the official documentation:

> if set to true, specifies that this volume has been created outside of
>   Compose. docker-compose up does not attempt to create it, and raises
>   an error if it doesn’t exist.
>
> external cannot be used in conjunction with other volume configuration
>   keys (driver, driver_opts).
>
> In the example below, instead of attempting to create a volume called
>   [projectname]_data, Compose looks for an existing volume simply called
>   data and mount it into the db service’s containers.

As an example:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data:
    external: true
```

> You can also specify the name of the volume separately from the name used to refer to it within the Compose file:

```
volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: actual-name-of-volume
```